# Eclipse IDE display Class Exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

The other day I was using Visual Studio and realized that it displayed the Exceptions a class throws with class documentation(Intellisense). My question is that can I get this same functionality with Eclipse cause sometime I forget what exception each class throws and how?

Comment: Search for Documenting a method with @throws annotation

Comment: Is Shift-F2 what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A class doesn't throw Exceptions a method does. You can see those Exceptions in the JavaDocs which are shown when you hover over a method. They are also shown next to the methods in the code completion popup. You can also use the `Javadoc` view from `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Javadoc` to get the Javadoc of the selected method.